# IEnumerable<T> provides two GetEnumerator methods - what is the difference between them?

Tags: ienumerable, ienumerator

When I emplement `IEnumerable<T>` interface I see two `GetEnumerator` methods: one returning `IEnumerator` and other `IEnumerator<T>`. When would I use one or another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` generic interface, you will pretty much always have to use the generic GetEnumerator method - unless you cast your object explicitly to (non-generic) IEnumerable.

The reason is backwards compatability with .NET 1.0/1.1 which didn't support generics.

Answer (score 35):

You usually implement both. One is the newer, generic version that returns a typesafe enumerator (`IEnumerator<T>`). The other one is for compatibility with Legacy code (returns `IEnumerator`). A typical implementation is:

```cs
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach(T item in items) {
        yield return item;
    }
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: this one helped me a lot, avoiding the extra-class for the nested enumerator!

Comment: +1. I also was googling to find a reference implementation that avoids the nested enumerator class and this was the first answer I came to.

Answer (score 13):

The reason there are two methods is because `IEnumerable<T>` inherits the `IEnumerable` interface so you are seeing the generic method from `IEnumerable<T>` and the non-generic method from `IEnumerable`.

Here is how you want to implement the interface in your type:

```cs
class Foo : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()   
    {
        // do your thing here
    }

    // do a EIMI here and simply call the generic method
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - EIMI =  Explicit interface member implementation

Comment: But how on earth `Foo : IEnumerable<Foo>` makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

Usually `GetEnumerator()` calls `GetEnumerator<T>()`, so there should not be much difference in behavior. As for why there are two methods, this is done for backwards compatibility and for use in situation where `T` is not of great interest (or is just unknown).

Answer (score 2):

The one is generic, the other one not. I believe the compiler prefers to use the generic overload.