# Thread safe SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, wrapper, sorteddictionary

I made a class that uses a `SortedDictionary` to store and manipulate data. The class works great except when it is implemented in a multi-threaded environment. Now, I would like to make the class thread safe by writing a wrapper class for the internal `SortedDictionary` class. I would like to use the Reader-Writer Locks to implement this but for now, I'm having problems just writing the wrapper class itself. Specifically, I'm not sure how to implement the `Enumerator` for the dictionary. Here is my complete code for the class as it stands now.

```
    public class ConcurrentSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    #region Variables
    SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict;
    #endregion
    #region Constructors
    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary()
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary(IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
    }

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
    }

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, comparer);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    public IComparer<TKey> Comparer
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _dict.Comparer;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _dict.Count;
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    { 
        get
        {
            return _dict[key];
        }

        set
        {
            _dict[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return new SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection(_dict);
        }
    }

    public SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection(_dict);
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Methods
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _dict.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dict.Clear();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _dict.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsValue(TValue value)
    {
        return _dict.ContainsValue(value);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
    {
        _dict.CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        return _dict.Equals(obj);
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dict.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _dict.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return _dict.Remove(key);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _dict.ToString();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return _dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When I compile the code, I get the error message:

> 'ConcurrentSortedDictionary' does not implement interface
>   member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'.
>   'ConcurrentSortedDictionary.GetEnumerator()' cannot
>   implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it
>   does not have the matching return type of
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

I looked at several posts here relating to this as a reference:

[How do I implement IEnumerable in my Dictionary wrapper class that implements IEnumerable<Foo>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692455/how-do-i-implement-ienumerable-in-my-dictionary-wrapper-class-that-implements-ie)
[What's the best way of implementing a thread-safe Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157933/whats-the-best-way-of-implementing-a-thread-safe-dictionary)

But I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After implementing the suggestion by dvnrrs, I now have the class working well. I even added a wrapper class for the IEnumerable interface to protect enumerations of the SortedDictionary (code modified from this example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56575/Thread-safe-enumeration-in-C). Here is the updated code with the Reader-Writer Locks included:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;

public class SafeEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    #region Variables

    // this is the (thread-unsafe)
    // enumerator of the underlying collection
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

    // this is the object we shall lock on. 
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

    #endregion 

    #region Constructor

    public SafeEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner, ReaderWriterLockSlim readWriteLock)
    {
        _enumerator = inner;
        _lock = readWriteLock;

        // Enter lock in constructor
        _lock.EnterReadLock();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // .. and exiting lock on Dispose()
        // This will be called when the foreach loop finishes
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IEnumerator

    // we just delegate actual implementation
    // to the inner enumerator, that actually iterates
    // over some collection

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return _enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _enumerator.Reset();
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _enumerator.Current; 
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Current; 
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class ConcurrentSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    #region Variables

    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _readWriteLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary()
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary(IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
    }

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
    }

    public ConcurrentSortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _dict = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, comparer);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IComparer<TKey> Comparer
    {
        get 
        {
            _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _dict.Comparer;
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _dict.Count;
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    { 
        get
        {
            _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _dict[key];
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _dict[key] = value;
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Keys
    {
        get
        {
            _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection(_dict);
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection Values
    {
        get
        {
            _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection(_dict);
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            _dict.Add(key, value);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            _dict.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.ContainsKey(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsValue(TValue value)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.ContainsValue(value);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            _dict.CopyTo(array, index);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.Equals(obj);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new SafeEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(_dict.GetEnumerator(), _readWriteLock);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new SafeEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(_dict.GetEnumerator(), _readWriteLock);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.GetHashCode();
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.Remove(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
        finally
        {
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If you have another question you should *ask a new question*.  Asking a question in an answer is not appropriate.

Comment: Hi, this still gave me the error:"Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated." but it only happens once very rarely so vast improvement on what I was using. Cheers

Comment: This implementation is not thread safe. Mistake is in the `GetEnumerator()` methods: enumerator is taken not under the lock. So the underlying collection may change in between enumerator is taken and iteration starts.

Comment: Also, `Keys` and `Values` properties has the same issue. Keys and values collections are created under the lock, but if you later want to iterate over them, it won't be thread safe. It's better to return a snapshotted copy of all the keys/values, just like `ConcurrentDictionary` does.

Comment: There are tons of pitfalls, for consumers, once they go beyond the enumerator itself, especially for reference types, unless you make an immutable deep copy of the collection to iterate over. Even `ConcurrentDictionary` can't save you from that. But the point of a thread-safe collection isn't to protect the contents referenced by the collection - it's to protect the structure of the dictionary itself. Thread safety beyond that point still requires you to do it yourself. Members of reference types inside the dictionary can still be corrupted by unsynchronized access by multiple threads.

Comment: That is to say that @andreycha is correct, about both statements. This class isn't thread-safe unless whatever gets the enumerator first creates the lock object, locks it, and then gets the enumerator. And, at that point, there's no point at all to this custom Enumerator class unless it is just modified to take care of exiting the lock for you or something, but that sounds like deadlock city to me. This answer badly needs to be unmarked as correct.

Comment: Seems to me that a much simpler and safer way to implement this would be to use ConcurrentDictionary, underneath, and have a property that returns an ImmutableSortedDictionary, by just calling ToImmutableSortedDictionary on the ConcurrentDictionary, to handle the snapshot creation. And, of course, the thread safety concerns of the contents itself still applies, for reference types.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return _dict.GetEnumerator();
}
```

You need:

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return _dict.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return _dict.GetEnumerator();
}
```

The second non-generic `GetEnumerator()` is an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and is needed as an unfortunate throwback to the days before generics and generic collections existed in C#.

See also: [IEnumerable<T> provides two GetEnumerator methods - what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560678/ienumerablet-provides-two-getenumerator-methods-what-is-the-difference-betwe) (and in particular [Michael B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/560700/1274314)).

**However** if you want enumeration to be thread-safe along with the rest of your class, you may also need to write your own thread-safe `IEnumerator` type which cooperates with the reader/writer locks in your class!

Comment: Hi dvnrrs, Thank you for the correction. This absolutely solved my problem! I just added the Reader-Writer implementation and updated my original question. I also added a wrapper class for IEnumerable based on a code example from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56575/Thread-safe-enumeration-in-C. It seems to also be working well although I ran into another problem which I mentioned in my edit to the original question.